# Is there any OpenAPI or Swagger definitions for Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, documentation

I would like to know if there are any OpenAPI or Swagger definitions available for Marketing Cloud API either REST or SOAP.

Thanks

Comment: OpenAPI is specification framework and swagger is a design tool for OpenAPI sepcification...and specification includes things that vary for each org(endpoint, attributes etc.)...so you should not expect API contract with generic requirements

Comment: @SanTosh actually Swagger is an old name of the OpenAPI before it got standardized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenAPI definition is published as the part of the official `mcsdk-automation-framework` - https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/mcsdk-automation-framework-core/blob/master/resources/sfmc-openapi-v2.json

It contains only public REST endpoints
There are also autogenerated SDK's for different languages

For SOAP you can use WSDL which you can get from your SFMC instance
https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/etframework.wsdl

See more info about WSDL in the [doc article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/wsdl-endpoint-links.htm)