# How to bring leads from salesforce to marketing cloud whitout the conector

Tags: marketing-cloud, leads, marketing-cloud-connect, data, data-import

So I have a question about the salesforce and marketing cloud.

Here at the company we have a salesforce org connected to marketing cloud. As we don't have multi-org functionality (and we don't plan to have it in the near future), this connection ends up going to all of our business units.

We are currently putting together a journey that sends email when a salesforce lead reaches a certain status. However, this lead is inserted in a salesforce org that is not connected to our marketing cloud, and at the moment I am not allowed by my superiors to make the connection because it is being used in another business unit.

The question here is: do you know any way to bring salesforce leads to marketing cloud other than the salesforce export method and import to cloud marketing?

Any link you send me will help :)

Comment: Write code in your Sales Cloud org to call MC APIs: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159901/how-do-i-create-a-contact-through-the-marketing-cloud-rest-api

Comment: Ok, but there is a way to doing it without using code?

Comment: Mulesoft or Flow + External Services. The [OpenAPI definitions of MC APIs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321509/is-there-any-openapi-or-swagger-definitions-for-marketing-cloud) _might_ work out of the box with External Services.

Comment: Do you have an example of code I can use to make this call?

Comment: The referenced Q&A above has the code