# Help setting up Marketing Cloud REST API as an External Service in Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, visual-workflow, auth-provider, external-services

I'm want to use External Services in salesforce to call the Marketing Cloud REST API in a flow.

I've done some digging on this and think the steps to do this are:

- Setup an Auth Provider
- Setup and External Service (using the above auth provider as credentials)
- Build a flow that utilises this external service to call the MC REST API
- Do some stuff with the returned JSON

I have everything setup on the Marketing Cloud side (I am using postman to get an access token and hit the relevant REST end points). But I need some help on the Salesforce side of things.

**Two questions:**

1. Does the above look right?
2. Can anyone point me in the direction of a guide/tutorial that will walk me through this? I'm stuck on some of the finer details around setting up the Auth Provider (and maybe the External Service once I get to that).

Comment: 1. Sure. 2. There isn't one for Ext Svcs -> MC. You can take a look at [External Services tutorial](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/external-services), sign up for a [Winter 21 pilot](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_extend_easily_add_actions.htm&type=5&release=228) of External Services being able to import OpenAPI service definitions, then try that on [Marketing Cloud OpenAPI service defs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321509/is-there-any-openapi-or-swagger-definitions-for-marketing-cloud).

Comment: You need to setup a named credential, not an auth provider.  Named credential setup is much simpler.  Once you do that you can create your external service and paste in the openapi spec that identigral posted above and that should get you started.  See this trailhead article https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/external-services/register-an-external-service also see the forcepanda website Narender has done a lot of posts recently on external services that helped me

Comment: Thanks both. Forcepanda has good articles. @gorav why do you say I don't need an auth provider? How else would I authorise via OAuth 2.0 with my marketing cloud managed package?

Comment: @ben you are right, you do need both for Oauth2.0.  if you use basic auth, then you do not need the auth provider - just the named credential. i had been using basic auth for my external services.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have the same issue: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/364131/salesforce-marketing-cloud-rest-api-from-salesforce-cloud-apex