# Setup the Name Credential and Auth Provider for Marketing Cloud API

Tags: namedcredentials, marketingcloudapi, auth-provider

We are intent to use Marketing Cloud API using Apex Callout.
Initially, I was trying to set up a **Name Credential** and **Auth Provider** for the **Server-Server** API Package on the MC side.
But with my testing, I've got the from debug log:
The NAMED_CREDENTIAL_REQUEST:

```
[.../rowset/, Method=GET, External Credential Type=EXTERNAL, HTTP Header Authorization=Not Set, Content-Type=null, Request Size bytes=-1, Retry on 401=True]
```

The NAMED_CREDENTIAL_RESPONSE_DETAIL:

```
{"documentation":"https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm","errorcode":0,"message":"Not Authorized"}
```

Somehow the Auth.Provider doesn't set the 'Authorization' in the header of the named credential callout...

my Named Credential settings:

[image]

my Auth.Provider settings:

[image]

As you can see for the Named Credential I also checked 'Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Header', I also tried with `req.setHeader('Authorization', '{!$Credential.OAuthToken}');` for the before the callout. It was still the same `Authorization=Not Set`.

Is there anything I did wrong? Thanks in advance.

I know there is a similar question here: [Salesforce Marketing cloud rest API from Salesforce Cloud (apex)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/364131/salesforce-marketing-cloud-rest-api-from-salesforce-cloud-apex)
But there was no answer there, and our use cases are slightly different. I hope my question can provide more details for the experts like you to gain more insight to provide us with the solution.

Comment: Recommend sticking with Apex + NC to implement`client_credentials` grant type (no auth provider). There are examples of this on here, do a search.